# Resize video using FFmpeg C API

Tags: android, c, api, ffmpeg

I am trying to resize video file on Android device using FFmpeg. Remark: I cant use FFmpeg as binary - in my case it should be used as shared library (only FFmpeg C API is accessible).

I did not find any documentation regarding video resizing, however it looks like algorithm is following:

```
10 OPEN video_stream FROM video.mp4
20 READ packet FROM video_stream INTO frame
30 IF frame NOT COMPLETE GOTO 20
40 RESIZE frame
50 WRITE frame TO converted_video.mp4
60 GOTO 20
```

Should I use [sws_scale](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/functions.html#sws_scale) function in order to resize frame? Is there any other (easier?) way to resize video file using FFmpeg C API?

Comment: You could just use the ffmpeg executable with exec if you wanted...

Comment: I cant use FFmpeg as binary - in my case it should be used as shared library (only FFmpeg C API is accessible).

Comment: Hey, did you manage to do so? can you past some code?

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, `sws_scale()` is the way to do this with recent FFmpeg versions. Despite the extra steps like preparing an `SwsContext` it's not that hard to use, and there are examples such as the tutorial on the site you referenced.

Older versions also had an `img_convert()` function which was a bit simpler to use, and for a while it was still in the library but not in the usual headers -- it still worked if you supplied your own prototype (taken from an older version).  This may still work, if you're willing to chance it -- though I haven't tried it with the latest versions.  It's probably safer and better to use `sws_scale()`, though.

It's also possible to handle the scaling outside of the FFmpeg libraries, but it's likely more trouble than it's worth in this case.  The Doxygen documentation for the libraries describes the `AVPicture` structure well enough to work with it directly, or transfer the image to/from some other form.  The main difficulty is ensuring you can work with or convert the color/pixel format used -- if you would have to convert it to another format, you should use `sws_scale()` for at least that much, if not the resizing as well.